# Scaling setting for multiple monitors

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have two monitors: DP1 3840x2160 60.00, HDMI3 1680x1050 59.95.

Right now my DPI setting is

**~/.Xresources**

```
xft.dpi: 145
Xcursor.size: 36
```

Since I use i3wm

**~/.config/i3/config**

```
exec xrandr --output DP1 --dpi 152
exec xrandr --output DP1 --auto --output HDMI3 --auto --panning 2520x1575+3840+0 --scale 1.5x1.5 --right-of DP1
```

It works fine when HDMI3 in landscape orientation.
Then I want to change it to portrait:

```
exec xrandr --output HDMI3 --rotate left
```

The display just broken.

Should I create a new mode for portrait resolution or something?

How should I config a portrait monitor?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Intel 6700k with HD Graphic 530